# Default selected values are not not displaying in MultiSelectList in Asp.Net MVC Razor view

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-5, multi-select

I have these fields in my model

```
public MultiSelectList Subjects { set; get; }
public string[] CCUsers { get; set; }
```

and in my controller I have set these properties as:

```
model.CCUsers = GetAdditionalCCusers(routingInstruction.ID);//returns already selected data from database
model.Subjects=ViewBag.CCUsers = new MultiSelectList(correspondenceInfo.SPUsers, "Title", "Title", model.CCUsers.ToList());
```

This is in my view:

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.CCUsers, Model.Subjects)
```

The problem is when the page get loaded the values which I am getting from database are not getting selected by default.

On debugging I can see that in `model.Subjects`, the Selected property of two values are set `true`.

Comment: If the value of CCUsers contains values which match values in the options, then they will be selected. Note there is no point setting `model.CCUsers.ToList()` in the `MultiSelectList` constructor since your binding to a property (its just ignored)

Comment: The values is model.CCUsers are "Admin" and "User 1"; and in model.Subjects.SelectedValues these are same.

Comment: Look at the html generated - do you have `<option value="Admin">SomeIdValue</option>` and `<option value="User 1">SomeIdValue</option>`? (but it seems odd that you have the option values that use the `Title` property and the display text using the `Id` property)

Comment: I have updated the post. I am using "Title" for both dataValueField and dataTextField. While debugging I can see two string values in CCUsers ("Admin","User 1") and the Subject has Subject.Item[0] ={ID=17,Title="Admin"}

Comment: and the html is rendering as `<select id="CCUsers" multiple="multiple" name="CCUsers"><option value="Admin">Admin</option>
<option value="User 1">User 1</option>
</select>`

Comment: Then if the value of `CCUsers` is `{ "Admin" ,"User 1" }`, those 2 options will be selected. I suggest you test with say `model.CCUsers = new string[] { "Admin: };` and check that the first one is selected. If not there is something else going on.

Comment: Try this but still not selected

Comment: Then there is something else causing the issue, because it works fine. - Test it with `model.CCUsers = new string[] { "Admin: }` and `model.Subjects = new MultiSelectList(new List<string>() { "Admin", "User 1" })` and the first option will be selected.